# non-type template parameter whose type depends on another parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to define a template function who has a type parameter and a non-type parameter. However, the type of the non-type parameter depends on the type parameter. It looks like the following:

```
template<typename T>
class A{
    typedef T* Pointer;
};

template<typename T, A<typename T>::Pointer P>
T fun(){
    return *P;
}

int main(){
    fun<int, (int*)0>();
}
```

If I compile the code, the compiler complains:

```
test.cpp:6:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 template<typename T, A<typename T>::Pointer P>
                                  ^
test.cpp:6:45: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘P’
 template<typename T, A<typename T>::Pointer P>
                                             ^
```

What should I do to make my code work? Thank you!

PS. The above code is just a example of the structure. I know the code itself is meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *almost* put the `typename` in the right place.

```
template<typename T, typename A<T>::Pointer P>
```

Also, the `Pointer` `typedef` needs to be public in order for this to work.

Comment: Thank you! Would you please explain or give a reference about why `typename` is needed in this case?

Comment: `fun()` could also be a friend of `A<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

It works when you fix the syntax and the access control:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:                                            // must be accessible!
    typedef T* Pointer;
};

template<typename T, typename A<T>::Pointer P>     // like this
T fun()
{
    return *P;
}

int main()
{
    fun<int, (int*)0>();
}
```