# Template parameters that depend on other template parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, eigen, eigen3

I have found a few similar questions (*e.g.* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365492/non-type-template-parameter-whose-type-depends-on-another-parameter)), but none of them really answer mine. Consider this code snippet:

```
template<unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols,typename arrtype>
class Variance
{
   double f(const arrtype &);
};

template<unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols>
double Variance<rows,cols,Eigen::Matrix<double,rows,cols>>
    ::f(const Eigen::Array<double,rows,cols> & M) 
{
  //do stuff
}
```

As you can see in the specialization, the type `arrtype` will depend on `rows` and `cols`. The code above results in a compiler error (g++ 5.4.0):

```
invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Variance<rows, cols, Eigen::Matrix<double, rows, cols> >
```

I have tried `typename arrtype<rows, cols>` in the template declaration, but then it complains that `arrtype` is not a type, which makes sense.

What is the proper way to use templated types that depend on other templated types?

Comment: @user463035818 Thank you very much for you comment. Could you elaborate a little bit? I don't get the chance to work as often as I'd like with templates, so I'm not very comfortable with them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simplified version of your code:

```
template<size_t rows, size_t cols> struct Foo {   double foo(); };

template<size_t rows> double Foo<rows,3>::f() { return 3;}
```

The error you get:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Foo<rows, 3ul>’
double Foo<rows,3>::f() { return 3;}
```

The problem isnt really that one of your template parameters depends on others, but the problem is that you cannot partially specialize a member without partially specializing the class.

This works:

```
template<size_t rows, size_t cols> struct Foo {   double foo(); };

template<size_t rows> struct Foo<rows,3> { double f() { return 3;}  };
```

Comment: To complete, depending on the context, it might be a good idea to make `f` it a free function to enable partial specialization.

Comment: *"you cannot define a specialized method of the class without specializing the class."*. You can do it, but you cannot **partially** specialize a method/function (and OP would require a partial specialization so specialize the class).

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks a lot, I knew that i was missing something, but I wasnt sure what it was.... better now?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to partial class specialization like in [user463035818's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49904997/27678) (or trying to fully-specialize the function) is a technique called *tagged dispatch*.

The way you do it is by creating overloaded helper functions to dispatch to, and allowing normal overloading to take over based on argument parameters.

Below I'll show how to specialize for an `Eigen::Array<double, rows, cols>`:

```
template<unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols,typename arrtype>
class Variance
{
public:
    double f(const arrtype& arg)
    {
        return f_impl(arg, tag<arrtype>{});
    }
private:
    template<class... T>
    struct tag{};

    template<class... T>
    double f_impl(const arrtype&, tag<T...>){
        std::cout << "catch-all function\n";
        return 42.0;
    }

    double f_impl(const arrtype&, tag<Eigen::Array<double, rows, cols>>){
        std::cout << "specialization for Eigen::Array<double, rows, cols>\n";
        return 1337.0;
    }
};
```

And now you can call it like so:

```
Variance<1, 1, int> non_specialized;
non_specialized.f(int{}); // prints "catch-all function"

Variance<1, 1, Eigen::Array<double, 1, 1>> specialized;
specialized.f(Eigen::Array<double, 1, 1>{}); // prints "specialization for Eigen::Array<double, rows, cols>"
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l8Ltmxayi0BEuVjw)

---

Tagged dispatch is very useful when you want to avoid copy-pasting nearly identical functions for both the base template class and your specialized class, or putting everything into some common base and using polymorphism.